# How to sort an array of Java-style package names in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of Java-style package names and want to sort it in a specific way. The sort order I want is generally alphabetically, but with the additional requirement that lowercase always goes either before or after uppercase, depending on a user supplied flag to the sorting function (which allows also a third option of leaving the original order alone).

Example:

```
const importStrings = [
  "foo.bar.Zonk",
  "lorem.ipsum.acme.Rocket",
  "foo.bar.BazFoo",
  "lorem.ipsum.Blah",
  "foo.bar.baz.Gnarf",
  "lorem.ipsum.acme.Amboss",
];
```

The order I want is either uppercase first on any given `.`:

```
[
  "foo.bar.BazFoo",
  "foo.bar.Zonk",
  "foo.bar.baz.Gnarf",
  "lorem.ipsum.Blah",
  "lorem.ipsum.acme.Amboss",
  "lorem.ipsum.acme.Rocket",
]
```

or lowercase first:

```
[
  "foo.bar.baz.Gnarf",
  "foo.bar.BazFoo",
  "foo.bar.Zonk",
  "lorem.ipsum.acme.Amboss",
  "lorem.ipsum.acme.Rocket",
  "lorem.ipsum.Blah",
]
```

Effectively, I want the sort order to be `A-Za-z`/`a-zA-Z` instead of `AaBb..Zz`/`aAbB..zZ`, which seems to be surprisingly difficult to achieve unless I'm missing something really, *really* obvious. All my previous experiments with various custom `Array.sort()` functions and `localeCompare()` options didn't yield the output I need.

My current approach kinda-works, but contains a ton of boilerplate and cruft, and I'm thinking that there *has* to be a better way of doing this. I currently split the individual strings on `.`, recursively build a object graph containing each "level" of the package name in an array, and then sort that array. That gives me the ordering I want, which I can then merge back together:

```
function createImportData(data, parts, sortFunction, reduceFunction) {
  const packageName = parts.shift();

  let localData = data.find((obj) => obj.value === packageName);
  if (!localData) {
    localData = { value: packageName, children: [] };
    data.push(localData);
  }

  if (parts.length) {
    createImportData(localData.children, parts, sortFunction, reduceFunction);
    localData.children = localData.children
      .reduce(reduceFunction, [[], []])
      .flatMap((array) => array.sort(sortFunction));
  }
}

function getSortFunction(options) {
  if (!shouldOrganizeImports(options)) {
    // leave all
    return (obj1, obj2) => 0;
  } else {
    return (obj1, obj2) => {
      obj1.value.localeCompare(obj2.value);
    };
  }
}

function getReduceFunction(options) {
  if (!shouldOrganizeImports(options)) {
    // just put it in a single array without changing anything
    return (groups, obj) => {
      groups[0].push(obj);
      return groups;
    };
  } else {
    const upperIndex = shouldOrganizeImportsUppercaseFirst(options) ? 0 : 1;
    const lowerIndex = shouldOrganizeImportsUppercaseFirst(options) ? 1 : 0;
    const reduce = (upperIndex, lowerIndex) => (groups, obj) => {
      obj.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() === obj.value.charAt(0)
        ? groups[upperIndex].push(obj)
        : groups[lowerIndex].push(obj);
      return groups;
    };
    return reduce(upperIndex, lowerIndex);
  }
}

//initial call looks like this:
  const importData = [];
  const sortFunction = getSortFunction(options);
  const reduceFunction = getReduceFunction(options);

  for (const importString of importStrings) {
    createImportData(
      importData,
      importString.split("."),
      sortFunction,
      reduceFunction
    );
  }
```

The generated structure looks like this, with each level's `children` array sorted the way I need:

```
[
  {
    value: "foo",
    children: [
      {
        value: "bar",
        children: [
          { value: "baz", children: [{ value: "Gnarf", children: [] }] },
          { value: "BazFoo", children: [] },
          { value: "Zonk", children: [] },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {value: "lorem", children: [/* etc.etc. */]}
]
```

How can I improve on my logic, or is this already the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach where the character are extended to two characters, depening on their case:

```
lower, after sorting
---------------------------------------------

 f o o . b a r . b a z .G  n a r f
 f o o . b a r .B  a zF  o o
 f o o . b a r .Z  o n k
 l o r e m . i p s u m . a c m e .A  m b o s s
 l o r e m . i p s u m . a c m e .R  o c k e t
 l o r e m . i p s u m .B  l a h

upper, after sorting
---------------------------------------------

f o o . b a r .  Ba z  Fo o 
f o o . b a r .  Zo n k 
f o o . b a r . b a z .  Gn a r f 
l o r e m . i p s u m .  Bl a h 
l o r e m . i p s u m . a c m e .  Am b o s s 
l o r e m . i p s u m . a c m e .  Ro c k e t
```

The the original data is mapped by the sorted indices.

```js
const
    sort = (array, priority) => {
        const order = priority === 'lower';
        return array
            .map((s, index) => {
                const o = { index, value: '' };
                for (const c of s) o.value += c === c.toLowerCase() === order ? ' ' + c : c + ' ';
                return o;
            })
            .sort((a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value))
            .map(({ index }) => array[index]);
    },
    data = ["foo.bar.Zonk", "lorem.ipsum.acme.Rocket", "foo.bar.BazFoo", "lorem.ipsum.Blah", "foo.bar.baz.Gnarf", "lorem.ipsum.acme.Amboss"],
    sorted1 = sort(data, 'lower'),
    sorted2 = sort(data, 'upper');

console.log(sorted1);
console.log(sorted2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That's a very distinct approach to sorting, I don't think I've ever seen this specific method before. Do you know if it has a particular name that I could google to learn more?

Comment: @Aldoro, sorry this has no name. it is an idea from me, maybe s/o has invented it before, i don't know. the advantage of this approach, it takes groups of characters and it allowes to use a simple sorting.

Answer (score 2):

That's a fairly idiosyncratic sort, but it's possible to do it a bit more concisely using [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator) along with breaking the package names into their individual parts and custom logic to *always* put something starting with upper case before/after something starting with lower case regardless of length:

```
// Tells us whether a string starst with an English uppercase char
// (may need tweaking for non-English)
const startsUppercase = /^[A-Z]/;
function sort(array, upperFirst) {
    // Get a collator for the current locale with the appropriate case first flag,
    // and grab its `compare` function
    const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, { caseFirst: upperFirst ? "upper" : "lower"});
    const { compare } = collator;
    // Get a direction flag based on the upper-first/lower-first flag
    const direction = upperFirst ? -1 : 1;
    // Sort
    array.sort((a, b) => {
        // Get the two package names split into their parts
        const aparts = a.split(".");
        const bparts = b.split(".");
        // Assume they're equal...
        let result = 0;
        // Loop through as long as A) they're still equal, and
        // B) we have both `a` and `b` parts
        const length = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
        for (let i = 0; result === 0 && i < length; ++i) {
            const apart = aparts[i];
            const bpart = bparts[i];
            const aupper = startsUppercase.test(apart);
            const bupper = startsUppercase.test(bpart);
            if (aupper && !bupper) {
                // `a` comes first/last
                result = direction;
            } else if (!aupper && bupper) {
                // `b` comes first/last
                result = -direction;
            } else {
                // Same case, compare remainder
                result = compare(apart, bpart);
            }
        }
        // If still no difference, compare on segment length
        if (result === 0) {
            return aparts.length - bparts.length;
        }
        return result;
    });
    return array;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const importStrings = [
    "foo.bar.Zonk",
    "lorem.ipsum.acme.Rocket",
    "foo.bar.BazFoo",
    "lorem.ipsum.Blah",
    "foo.bar.baz.Gnarf",
    "lorem.ipsum.acme.Amboss",
];

// Tells us whether a string starst with an English uppercase char
// (may need tweaking for non-English)
const startsUppercase = /^[A-Z]/;
function sort(array, upperFirst) {
    // Get a collator for the current locale with the appropriate case first flag,
    // and grab its `compare` function
    const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, { caseFirst: upperFirst ? "upper" : "lower"});
    const { compare } = collator;
    // Get a direction flag based on the upper-first/lower-first flag
    const direction = upperFirst ? -1 : 1;
    // Sort
    array.sort((a, b) => {
        // Get the two package names split into their parts
        const aparts = a.split(".");
        const bparts = b.split(".");
        // Assume they're equal...
        let result = 0;
        // Loop through as long as A) they're still equal, and
        // B) we have both `a` and `b` parts
        const length = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
        for (let i = 0; result === 0 && i < length; ++i) {
            const apart = aparts[i];
            const bpart = bparts[i];
            const aupper = startsUppercase.test(apart);
            const bupper = startsUppercase.test(bpart);
            if (aupper && !bupper) {
                // `a` comes first/last
                result = direction;
            } else if (!aupper && bupper) {
                // `b` comes first/last
                result = -direction;
            } else {
                // Same case, compare remainder
                result = compare(apart, bpart);
            }
        }
        // If still no difference, compare on segment length
        if (result === 0) {
            return aparts.length - bparts.length;
        }
        return result;
    });
    return array;
}

console.log(`Upper first:`);
console.log(sort(importStrings.slice(), true));
console.log(`Lower first:`);
console.log(sort(importStrings.slice(), false));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If the array is large, it might be worth pre-splitting the package names so you do it only once rather than repeatedly (since the same string is often presented to the `sort` callback in the process of sorting large arrays). It's not a big change, see `***`:

```
// Tells us whether a string starst with an English uppercase char
// (may need tweaking for non-English)
const startsUppercase = /^[A-Z]/;
function sort(array, upperFirst) {
    // Get a collator for the current locale with the appropriate case first flag,
    // and grab its `compare` function
    const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, { caseFirst: upperFirst ? "upper" : "lower"});
    const { compare } = collator;
    // Get a direction flag based on the upper-first/lower-first flag
    const direction = upperFirst ? -1 : 1;
    // *** Get the pre-split package names
    const names = new Map(array.map(name => [name, name.split(".")]));
    // Sort
    array.sort((a, b) => {
        // Get the two package names split into their parts
        const aparts = names.get(a); // ***
        const bparts = names.get(b); // ***
        // Assume they're equal...
        let result = 0;
        // Loop through as long as A) they're still equal, and
        // B) we have both `a` and `b` parts
        const length = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
        for (let i = 0; result === 0 && i < length; ++i) {
            const apart = aparts[i];
            const bpart = bparts[i];
            const aupper = startsUppercase.test(apart);
            const bupper = startsUppercase.test(bpart);
            if (aupper && !bupper) {
                // `a` comes first/last
                result = direction;
            } else if (!aupper && bupper) {
                // `b` comes first/last
                result = -direction;
            } else {
                // Same case, compare remainder
                result = compare(apart, bpart);
            }
        }
        // If still no difference, compare on segment length
        if (result === 0) {
            return aparts.length - bparts.length;
        }
        return result;
    });
    return array;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const importStrings = [
    "foo.bar.Zonk",
    "lorem.ipsum.acme.Rocket",
    "foo.bar.BazFoo",
    "lorem.ipsum.Blah",
    "foo.bar.baz.Gnarf",
    "lorem.ipsum.acme.Amboss",
];

// Tells us whether a string starst with an English uppercase char
// (may need tweaking for non-English)
const startsUppercase = /^[A-Z]/;
function sort(array, upperFirst) {
    // Get a collator for the current locale with the appropriate case first flag,
    // and grab its `compare` function
    const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, { caseFirst: upperFirst ? "upper" : "lower"});
    const { compare } = collator;
    // Get a direction flag based on the upper-first/lower-first flag
    const direction = upperFirst ? -1 : 1;
    // *** Get the pre-split package names
    const names = new Map(array.map(name => [name, name.split(".")]));
    // Sort
    array.sort((a, b) => {
        // Get the two package names split into their parts
        const aparts = names.get(a); // ***
        const bparts = names.get(b); // ***
        // Assume they're equal...
        let result = 0;
        // Loop through as long as A) they're still equal, and
        // B) we have both `a` and `b` parts
        const length = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
        for (let i = 0; result === 0 && i < length; ++i) {
            const apart = aparts[i];
            const bpart = bparts[i];
            const aupper = startsUppercase.test(apart);
            const bupper = startsUppercase.test(bpart);
            if (aupper && !bupper) {
                // `a` comes first/last
                result = direction;
            } else if (!aupper && bupper) {
                // `b` comes first/last
                result = -direction;
            } else {
                // Same case, compare remainder
                result = compare(apart, bpart);
            }
        }
        // If still no difference, compare on segment length
        if (result === 0) {
            return aparts.length - bparts.length;
        }
        return result;
    });
    return array;
}

console.log(`Upper first:`);
console.log(sort(importStrings.slice(), true));
console.log(`Lower first:`);
console.log(sort(importStrings.slice(), false));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan - Ah, I see what you mean. Yeah, that approach could totally work. You might need to be careful of the padding char, but...

Comment: @mplungjan - Please ping me if you do post it, I'm keen to see what it looks like but have to force myself to go do real work now. :-D

Comment: I will not post - I saw yours and decided against it :)

Comment: @mplungjan - Fair enough. :-) Still, it was a neat idea.